# Jensen's alpha with timing activities

Tags: performance-evaluation, funds, mutual-fund

Why is Jensen’s Alpha not an appropriate measure of performance anymore, if the fund manager is a perfect market timer as stated for example in the Treynor-Mazuy-model or the Henriksson-Merton-model?